# How to debug Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

> whatever error occurs in Codeigniter 4 Its always showing default message
>   [image: Error message default from codeigniter 4]
>
> How to get exact error message in Codeigniter 4

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the constructor.

Comment: tried @BeingprabhU Nothing happen

Comment: put that inside the function where you are facing issue

Comment: even put inside also not works anyother way ?

Comment: How about this `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`??

Comment: Did that work??

Comment: No its not works!!

Comment: @elango, please refer to https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/logging.html for error logging. I'm not sure why the other solutions didn't work for you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rename the `env` file as `.env`, then removed # from CI_ENVIRONMENT  and modified

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
```

into

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow the following guidlines from [docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html)

> Copy or rename the env file to .env. Open it up.
>
> Uncomment the line with `CI_ENVIRONMENT` on it, and change `production` to `development`

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

and

Set the base url properly if you are not using PHP's built-in server

**app/config/App.php**

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/path_to_CI/public';
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to rename :

> env

to

> .env

And uncomment #CI_ENVIRONMENT = development to CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to the index.php file at the top. Final Solution

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Answer (score 1):

go to .env file in base file
uncomment #CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
to CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

Answer (score 1):

There are something you need to Debug

1. Rename the `env` file to `.env`

After Rename open the `.env` file. it looks like this.

[image]

Change this line

```
# CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
```

to

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

After that try to create an error, then you will see error page like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your directory project and open .env file
Change this

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
```

To this

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```