# why Whoops! error showing in codeigniter-4

Tags: codeigniter-4

i just copy codeingiter 4 in my XAMPP for Linux 7.4.3 which have PHP Version 7.4.3
but getting error like
Whoops!

We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501607/how-to-debug-codeigniter-4 - Same Problem and same solution.

Answer (score 12):

> Rename the **env** file as **.env**, then remove # from CI_ENVIRONMENT  and modify

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
```

> into

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

Comment: Actually I was looking for to error-reporting option and above solutions works. Cool!

Answer (score 3):

By Defaults CI 4 comes with production platform so it not showing the errors on the frontend. To see the errors, Open .htaccess file from the root and then enter

```
SetEnv CI_ENVIRONMENT development
```

it change the environment to development
the alternate way open .env file and then change the CI_ENVIRONMENT to development like that

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

Remember don't forget to remove # from the begining

Answer (score 1):

Pleaase try to install using composer
go to htdocs folder 
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root -s rc
replace project-root by your project folder name 
and then 
cd your_project_name

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter 4 source code have a folder named

> **writable**

, just update it's access permission. Sometimes it'll help to get rid of Whoops. [Also can check the video for Ubuntu / Linux](https://youtu.be/FSXtgdUzV_8)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter starts up in production mode. This is a safety feature to keep your site a bit more secure in case settings are messed up once it is live. So first let’s fix that. Copy or rename the `env` file to `.env`. Open it up. Uncomment the line with `CI_ENVIRONMENT` on it, and change `production` to `development`:

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = development
```

If you are using XAMPP, write `extension = intl` in the PHP file (`php.ini`).